# Converting a propositional formula to DNF form

Tags: logic, disjunctive-normal-form

I got a propositional formula and would like to know on how to construct a DNF equivalent step by step.

Here goes the formula:
    P<->(¬Q->R)

Comment: Possibility one: Straight up convert it by resolving the implications into $\vee$'s and then use distributivity and Moore's law to obtain a DNF. Possibility two (takes longer and is not that commonly used for such formulae): create a Karnaugh-Veitch-Diagram and simply read off the DNF. There should be enough resources explaining how to.

Comment: @greedoid This question is straightforward and relatively easy to answer. Why was it closed as off-topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way, which is conceptually illuminating about what's going on in finding DNF forms.

Write down a truth-table for the formula:

> $P\quad Q \quad R\quad\quad (P \leftrightarrow (\neg Q \to R))\\
>  T\quad T\quad T\ \quad\quad\quad T\\ T\quad T\quad F\ \quad\quad\quad
>  T\\ T\quad F\quad T\ \quad\quad\quad T\\ T\quad F\quad F\
>  \quad\quad\quad F\\ F\quad T\quad T\ \quad\quad\quad F\\ F\quad T\quad
>  F\ \quad\quad\quad F\\ F\quad F\quad T\ \quad\quad\quad F\\ F\quad
>  F\quad F\ \quad\quad\quad T$

Now look at the lines where the wff comes out true and write down the conjunction corresponding in the obvious way to the assignment of truth-values to the atoms on each of those line:

> $(P \land Q \land R)\\
> (P \land Q \land \neg R)\\
> (P \land \neg Q \land R)\\
> (\neg P \land \neg Q \land \neg R)$

So our wff is true just whenever one of those conjunctions is true. So

> Take the disjunction of those conjunctions

And we have a wff in DNF which is equivalent to the original one! Moreover, we see *why* the resulting wff is the correct DNF form.

Comment: but how is the step when we use the logical equivalence instead of truth table ?

Answer (score 1):

Begin with the disjunctive eqivalent form of the biconditional:

$$\def\getsto{\mathop{\leftrightarrow}} {p\getsto(\neg q\to r)\\ 
 (p\wedge(\neg q\to r))\vee(\neg p\wedge\neg(\neg q\to r))}$$

Then apply the conditional equivalence, negation of conditional, and distribution.

That is all.